# Populating a matrix with only a single list input

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, matrix

I have a code snippet that creates a matrix by populating the upper elements one by one and populate the lower elements afterwards (if the upper element is `x` then the lower is `1/x`)

```
n = 4
m = np.ones([n, n])
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
         if i < j:
             x = input()
             m[i, j] = float(x) 
             m[j, i] = 1 / float(x)
```

In the second code I can populate the matrix at once, but I need to populate the elements row-wise from top left to bottom right

```
n = int(input())
entries = list(map(int, input().split()))
matrix = np.array(entries).reshape(n, n)
```

My question is: is there any way can I populate the upper triangle of the matrix first like the first snippet, but only by entering a list once like the second snippet?

Ex.

n = 3

Input = 2 3 4 (list)

```
Expected output=
[[1.         2.         3.        ]
 [0.5        1.         4.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.25       1.        ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) is your friend here. This function supplies the indices of the upper triangle of a matrix. You can use the indices to assign your flat list into the portion of the matrix you want:

```
n = int(input())
entries = np.array(list(map(int, input().split())))
matrix = np.ones((n, n))
r, c = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
matrix[r, c] = entries
matrix[c, r] = 1 / entries
```

Since your matrices are square, supplying both `n` and the list is redundant because the length of the list must be a [triangular number](https://oeis.org/A000217). `len(entries) = (n**2 - n) / 2`, only has a valid integer solution when `1 + 8 * len(entries)` is an odd perfect square:

```
entries = np.array(list(map(int, input().split())))
d = np.sqrt(1 + 8 * entries.size)
if np.round(d) != d or d % 2:
    raise ValueError('invalid number of entries')
n = (d + 1) // 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what ive been looking for!

Comment: hi, @Mad Physicist I'm afraid I wasn't thorough when checking, it seems that its not the answer I m looking for since the example (n) was too small. If I have n=4, and entries=1 2 3 4 5 6 I'm expecting that the bottom triangle 'mirrors' the top triangle of matrix. Here's another example to let you know the difference.

I'm expecting
`[[1,1,2,3],       
  [1,1,4,5],
  [0.5,0.25, 1,6],
  [0.3,0.2,0.16666667,1]]`

Instead of 

`[[1,1,2,3],       
 [1,1,4,5],
 [0.5,0.33333333, 1,6],
 [0.25,0.2,0.16666667,1]]`

Please do help me if you know how i can do this, thanks

Comment: @manacoder. You're right. I fixed the index. Should have been swapping the two components of triu_indices instead of generating a new set with tril_indices.